# Animate position when neighbour elements faded out

Tags: jquery, css, animation, html-lists, css-transitions

I have multiple `li` elements in a row, if I hide all of them with jquery `fadeOut()` function, except one, it jumps immediately to the left of the parent `ul` element. Is there a way to animate this 'jump', with jquery or css?

Comment: Not possible with CSS...you can't animate display which is effectively what you are doing.

Comment: What you are asking for is rather unnatural. Simplest approach is to animate the elements' width to zero instead of fading out.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 good idea, will use this solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery transit library...

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: my problem is that I don't have fixed position, it's responsive, I don't change any coordinates, width, margin, etc.. it's position changes because of the element to the left disappears

Answer (score 0):

I'm animating the elements' opacity to zero and parallelly as @Roamer-1888 suggested I'm also animating the width of the elements to zero.